# IAP ( In App Purchase ) sample for MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I need to implement InApp Purchase in my monotouch app, but I cannot find any project sample on the Xamarin website ( http://samples.xamarin.com/iOS ) or in the monotouch samples collection on GitHub ( https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples ).

Any help is appeciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm working on a MonoTouch In-App Purchase sample, you can check out the code here:

https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-samples/tree/master/InAppPurchase

The sample contains two projects, one that demonstrates Consumable purchases and one that demonstrates NonConsumable purchases.

NOTE: the example does not yet demonstrate RECEIPT VERIFICATION, so you'll have to add this in yourself (why? see [hack](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/07/20/in-app-purchase-vulnerability-to-be-fixed-in-ios-6-apple-offers-best-practices-to-developers/), [fix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012484)). 
Check out @redth's server-side code to help build your own receipt verification logic with ASP.NET:
https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp/tree/master/JdSoft.Apple.AppStore

You might also consider this services like [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/) or [Beeblex](https://www.beeblex.com/) (although I have not tried them, so can't) for receipt verification.

FYI my sample code is based in-part on @jtclancey's AppStore code here:
https://github.com/Clancey/ClanceyLib

Finally, there's a bit of set-up required for In-App Purchases (registering your bank details with Apple, setting up the products in the iOS Developer Portal, Provisioning your app correctly). These steps are the same for MonoTouch and Objective-C, so this [Apple setup doco](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html) might help. You should also read Apple's [In-App Purchase programming docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), for familiarity.

Comment: Thank you CraigD, that is a great help! I'm looking forward to the receipt verification code if you plan to add it to the sample.

Comment: Yes, some guidance on receipt verification is to come. Especially with the recent hacking revelations!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what do you mean by "monotouch" but I implemented In-App purchased in my iPad project using this tutorial. This is the best out there. Just go through it, download sample and you'll get what you need for a simple yet awesome In-App feature in your project.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Comment: I mean sample projects that use the MonoTouch framework ( http://xamarin.com/monotouch/ ), that allows iOS apps to be written in C#. The example you linked is not written in C# but in Objective-C. I need a C# example project showing how to make In App Purchases.