# struggling testing IOS in app purchase with xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, xamarin

For the last couple of days I have been struggling trying to set up the enviroment to test in app purchase in xamarin. Their [docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/in-app_purchasing/part_1_-_in-app_purchase_basics_and_configuration) page is not very clear on what it needs to be done, at least for me.

For what I have researched, I need to sign a contract with apple, which requires me to give apple some information about my bank account, taxes, etc. That information is going to take a little while, maybe a week. So without contract, can I test in the sandbox mode in app purchase?

So far, I have created a development provisioning profile, my app id and bundle id as well, the products which I am going to sell within my app, and my test users. I tried getting product info from my device, but it did not work, no error, or app crash. Probably I am missing something here which causes this behavior.

I read in this [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html) that I need to install my provisioning profile and configure xcode to sign the app with this profile. How do I do this in xamarin studio?

Also, I need to tell xcode whats the application bundle id, again, how do I do this?

I read the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and gave me an overall understanding about the architecture needed to implement in app purchases, but I am failing on the little details.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

CraigD's answer to this may help: [IAP ( In App Purchase ) sample for MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576603/iap-in-app-purchase-sample-for-monotouch)

It doens't touch on live testing per se, but Craig's github example may help you with those details of implementation.